# Function works only once

Tags: jquery

My function works only once when I click on blue, if I want to make it black again, it no longer works.

What's the problem?
Is there an easier way to make that?

I know it works, but not in this way. I would take the value to the next page, and I thought its the simplest way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x;

    $("#dark").click(function(){
        dark(x);
        entscheid (x);
        }); 

    $("#blue").click(function(){
        blue(x);
        entscheid (x);
        }); 

    function blue(x){
        var x=0;    
    }

    function dark(x){
        var x=1;    
    }

    function entscheid(x){
        if(x==1){
          $("nav").attr("class","navigation-bar dark fixed-top");
          $(".dropdown-menu").attr("class","dropdown-menu dark");
          $(".heading").attr("class", "heading bg-dark fg-white");
          $(".container-middleBlue, .container-middleDark ").attr("class","container-middleDark");
        }
        else{
          $("nav").attr("class","navigation-bar blue fixed-top");
          $(".dropdown-menu").attr("class","dropdown-menu blue");
          $(".heading").attr("class", "heading bg-blue fg-white");
          $(".container-middleDark, .container-middleBlue").attr("class","container-middleBlue");
        }
    }
    })
```

Comment: why not use `entscheid(1)` or `entscheid(0)` in click callbacks ?, the `x` you defined in blue and dark functions are local to these function, not the same `x` you defined in the onready function

Comment: Can you paste it on a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions:

```
function blue(x){
    var x=0;    
}

function dark(x){
    var x=1;    
}
```

are creating and modifying a local variable, not your higher scoped variable `x`.  Because you  have `var` in front of `x`, it is declaring a new variable that is local only to this function.  Thus, they don't change the higher scoped variable that you are passing when you call `entscheid (x);`

---

I don't quite understand why you're using this other variable at all as you can just pass the desired value to your `entscheid` function and not use the global at all.

```
$("#dark").click(function(){
    entscheid(1);
}); 

$("#blue").click(function(){
    entscheid(0);
});
```